# IP Address Lookup in a Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, ip-address

I'm writing a Firefox extension and I need to find the ip address of the currently loaded page.  I can get the hostname of the page with window.location.host, but is there any way to find the ip for that hostname?

I tried looking for the answer at the Mozilla Developer Center but was unable to find anything.

EDIT: I would use something like PHP to do this, but cannot, because it's a firefox extension, running on the client side only.  I have no web server to do back end PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look at how the [ShowIP Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/590) does it.

Comment: This led me in the right direction, to the "nsIDNSService" component.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
var cls = Cc['@mozilla.org/network/dns-service;1'];
var iface = Ci.nsIDNSService;
var dns = cls.getService(iface); //dns object

var nsrecord = dns.resolve(HOSTNAME_HERE, true); //resolve hostname
while (nsrecord && nsrecord.hasMore()){
   alert(nsrecord.getNextAddrAsString()); //here you are
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If not a PHP Lookup, do a simple nslookup, or dig for hostname string.

Comment: is there a cross platform way to do an nslookup from a firefox extension?

Comment: Cross-platform (u mean various desktops, not iphone/symbian et al) nslookup is available in linux/windows, and i think must be available in mac too

Comment: I mean cross platform meaning *from javascript* in a firefox extension, on any platform firefox runs on.