# How to get local IP from Firefox extension code

Tags: javascript, sockets, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm writing a Firefox extension that uses [`nsIServerSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIServerSocket) to listen for socket connections. I'm looking for a way for the extension code to programmatically learn the local network address of the machine running the Firefox extension. This information gets communicated to a client on the local network out-of-band such that it can open a socket connection to the extension.

My research into this has so far only turned up individuals wishing to find the ip address [of loaded websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082728/ip-address-lookup-in-a-firefox-extension) by way of [DNS resolution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDNSService) or using [Java applets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510526/get-the-correct-local-ip-adress-from-java-applet)) which won't be appropriate for a FF extension. The Mozilla Developer pages on the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_geolocation) mentions:

> "data is exchanged including WiFi Access Point data, an access token (similar to a 2 week cookie), and the user's IP address"

but does not indicate an API to access the user's IP address directly.

My only idea at this point is to invoke a local process using [`nsIProcess`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIProcess) and parse the IP from there. This seems awfully hackish and would have to be handled on a per-OS basis. I.e. do I run ifconfig, netcfg, ipconfig? With what args?

Is anyone aware of a better solution?

Comment: Thanks for the link-fix Bergi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [`nsIDNSService` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDNSService) here as well - it has a `myHostName` property that can be resolved:

```js
var dns = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/dns-service;1"]
                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIDNSService);
var myName = dns.myHostName;
var record = dns.resolve(myName, 0);
while (record.hasMore())
  alert(record.getNextAddrAsString());
```

You should expect it to produce multiple addresses and not all of them will be valid - even for the local network you will get at least two addresses (IPv6 and IPv4), in addition to that you might get a Teredo address, addresses from virtual adapters installed by VMWare & Co. and more.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate the heads-up about multiple interface addresses.

Comment: Hey @Wladimir-Palant, I know this has been a while, but if you know the answer, it would really help. Having read this post, does this mean that any Firefox addon could potentially read your local IP address even if you are using an anonymous proxy configured through Firefox? In other words, an addon can always read the local IP address despite having a proxy in place?

Comment: @DomainsFeatured: Firefox add-ons are currently not sandboxed, they have full access to your computer - so they can do lots of things. If `nsIDNSService` didn't exist they could run external commands in order to read out your network configuration. Or they could simply disable proxy settings temporarily. Web Extensions are going to change that, but even then I'd say that you better trust the add-ons you have installed. On the bright side, add-ons reviewed by addons.mozilla.org are usually fine - the review makes sure that they do what they claim to do.

Comment: Hey @Wladimir-Palant, thanks so much for confirming that addons do have access to local IP info even without 'nsIDNSService'. If you get a moment, I think you could answer this question better than most people and I'll select your answer correct and upvote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582880/how-do-firefox-extensions-use-ip-address-with-anonymous-proxy-original-ip-may-b

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet that the IP address mentioned in the Geolocation API is not the local computer's IP address. I mean, where in the world is 192.168.0.100, hmm? It's just not a useful piece of information, in general.

Since you're dealing with a local network, could you set up a small web page that just prints out the client's address? Then you could learn your IP by requesting that web page.

Comment: Good point RE: the Geolocation API.

The purpose/deployment of my extension precludes the assumption that I can run a separate service to echo back a requesting ip. Otherwise that would have been a potential idea. Thanks!